# Java "confuses" class with datatype (enumeration)

Tags: java, enumeration

I'm doing an assignment in `Java` where I'm supposed to use the `enumeration` type `MONTH` that I've imported in my project. My teacher has written that "There is a special function that will convert a number to it's month:
`Month.month(8)`".

I've written `Month month = Month.month(4);` (where the variable month should have the value april), but it says that

> "the method month is undefined for the type month".

As I understand it, `Java` interprets the "Month" after the equal sign as a data/enumeration type, but I want it to be the class from which I use the function `month` (they both have the name `Month`). My classmates has used it without a problem and as far as I can see I've imported my teachers code correctly.

Eternally grateful for any help.

Comment: Please add code.

Answer (score 3):

If you have two classes (or enums) with same name you can use FQN (Fully Qualified Name).

For example if you have enum `Month` in package `myenums` and class `Month` in package `myclasses` you can write:

```
myenums.Month month = myclasses.Month.month(4);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use Month.of(monthNumber).name();

if you do,

```
Month month = Month.of(8);
System.out.println(month);
```

output will be AUGUST

Comment: @ronaldfisher your welcome, you can upvote if it solved your problem.